# Split varchar into separate columns in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm in a bit of a pickle:  I've been asked to take in comments starting with a specific string from a database, and separate the result into separate columns.

For example -- if a returned value is this:

```
COLUMN_ONE
--------------------
'D7ERROR username'
```

The return needs to be:

```
COL_ONE    COL_TWO
--------------------
D7ERROR   username
```

Is it even possible to define columns once the result set has been structured just for the sake of splitting a string into two?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Depends on the consistency of the data - assuming a single space is the separator between what you want to appear in column one vs two:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(t.column_one, 1, INSTR(t.column_one, ' ')-1) AS col_one,
       SUBSTR(t.column_one, INSTR(t.column_one, ' ')+1) AS col_two
  FROM YOUR_TABLE t
```

Oracle 10g+ has regex support, allowing more flexibility depending on the situation you need to solve.  It also has a regex substring method...

Reference:

- [SUBSTR](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/substr.php)
- [INSTR](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/instr.php)

Comment: Minor detail... This will include the space as part of the first column in the output.  You probably want that to be SUBSTR(t.column_one, 1, INSTR(t.column_one, ' ')-1)

Comment: thank you so much, i've been searching for so long in google. just found it here. you really saved my day. I love you sooooooo much :*

Answer (score 46):

With REGEXP_SUBSTR is as simple as:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.column_one, '[^ ]+', 1, 1) col_one,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.column_one, '[^ ]+', 1, 2) col_two
FROM YOUR_TABLE t;
```

Comment: This is very useful, but it only works with one char (white-space char). How can you modify this to work with more than one char, one that is guaranteed not to exist in the content (eg ' ' -> '~~' or something else unusual)?

Comment: I know I am resurructing an old question, @CharlesHenry - Did you try it? just replace the space with ~~ `select regexp_substr('123~~45,6,7', '[^~~]+', 1, 1), regexp_substr('123~~45,6,7', '[^~~]+', 1, 2) from dual`

Comment: I ended up using CASE and NVL statements to get it working. It runs **much** quicker than regex as these functions are a core part of Oracle.

Comment: Great tip. This is more flexible than substr since you can have variable length. I'm using dates substr can work, but I find regex_substr easier to read and understand. I've had some unexpected results with substr, so prefer regex_substr better.

Answer (score 4):

Simple way is to convert into column

```
SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE (SPLIT ('19869,19572,19223,18898,10155,'))

CREATE TYPE split_tbl as TABLE OF VARCHAR2(32767);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION split (p_list VARCHAR2, p_del VARCHAR2 := ',')
   RETURN split_tbl
   PIPELINED IS
   l_idx PLS_INTEGER;
   l_list VARCHAR2 (32767) := p_list;
   l_value VARCHAR2 (32767);
BEGIN
   LOOP
      l_idx := INSTR (l_list, p_del);

      IF l_idx > 0 THEN
         PIPE ROW (SUBSTR (l_list, 1, l_idx - 1));
         l_list := SUBSTR (l_list, l_idx + LENGTH (p_del));
      ELSE
         PIPE ROW (l_list);
         EXIT;
      END IF;
   END LOOP;

   RETURN;
END split;
```

Comment: While it would be possible to create a pipelined function that operates in this way, `split` is not a built-in function in Oracle.

Comment: Allan, here is the function details  in oracle , link                                                http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13292_01/pt849pbr0/eng/psbooks/tpcl/chapter.htm?File=tpcl/htm/tpcl02.htm

Comment: That's the documentation for Peopletools, not the Oracle RDBMS.