# Splitting the output of sys_connect_by_path as columns in an Oracle CONNECT BY SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have an Oracle SQL query that uses Oracle's `CONNECT BY` clause which returns the following output

```
Level   Path
1       A
2       A -> B
3       A -> B -> C
4       A -> B -> C -> D
```

The query returns the level and the path (Using `sys_connect_by_path` and '`->`' as the separator) as two column.

Is it possible to make each item in the path in its own column? For example, in the above output i know there will be a maximum of 4 levels/columns. How can i make the output as shown below:

```
Level   Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4
1       A
2       A        B
3       A        B       C  
4       A        B       C      D
```

I dont have to use sys_connect_by_path so if it is possible to put the values into columns without using sys_connect_by_path then please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This seems to work:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/5206731/12601

Answer (score 0):

Introduce in Oracle 11g the operator `PIVOT` lets you write cross tabulation queries that rotate rows into columns