# How to split multi valued column and insert the values in individual column?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Table 1

[image]

Table 2

[image]

How to split the multi valued columns and keep it in individual Column in `ORACLE DB`?
     Here `Table 1` is the source table and `"Product Region"` column contains multiple names and I would like to split it and the sample output is in `Table 2`.

Can anyone please give me a guidance?
Advance thanks.

Comment: post the data ...images wont able to do much

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199849/split-varchar-into-separate-columns-in-oracle

Comment: Tough luck, but now you've learned the lesson to never store data like ; separated items...