# How to split the column base on the underscore

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, split

```
****Original          Column    After separated****
CustomerID  CustomerID1 CustomerID2 CustomerID3 CustomerID4
1_2_R_0           1             2           R      0
3_3_0             3             3           0    
4_2               4             2
```

Customer ID is the original column from this I need to split into multiple column base on the underscore to *customerID1*, *customerID2*, *customerID3* and *customerID4*.

[image]

Comment: Tag the question with the database you use.

Comment: Tag your DB. For oracle, refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199849/split-varchar-into-separate-columns-in-oracle

Comment: How many CustomerID's may be found in a column?

Comment: Tag it so that we could close it as a duplicate of ...

Comment: SQL Server 2008

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server+split

Comment: It can be many customer but the scenario above is the distinct customerID

Comment: `STRING_SPLIT` could have made it simpler for you, but it's not supported in 2008.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I split a string so I can access item x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x)

Comment: There will be thousand of customers but number of underscore(_) for each customer can be three or  two or  one only.

Answer (score 2):

Since there is a max of only 4 IDs, you could use parsename().   However, I would opt for the XML approach.

**Example**

```
Select A.CustomerID
      ,B.*
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
    Select CustomerID1 = xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(100)')
          ,CustomerID2 = xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(100)')
          ,CustomerID3 = xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(100)')
          ,CustomerID4 = xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(100)')
     From  (values (cast('<x>' + replace([CustomerID],'_','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml))) X(xDim)
 ) B
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: Hi John, Its working fine exactly as i needed. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Maqbul If this solution is working as you expect then accept this ans.