# How Can I Flatten the Results of a SQL Query - Transposing Rows to Columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a table that I want to join some other tables on to. The table called "OfficePers" has a field for the Office Location ID as well as a field for the IDs of people who work in that location and another field with their names. For example, the table is of the following format:

```
| OfficeLocation | PersonID |
|--------------  | -------- |    
|321             |   2323   |   
|321             |   2355   |   
|321             |   1234   |   
|321             |   7899   |   
|321             |   32091  |   
|321             |   777    |       
|1654            |   4232   |   
|121243          |   345    |       
|121243          |   343    |       
|121243          |   111    |
```

What I want to do is create a subquery that returns one result per office location and creates aliases for each personID and name - so the above table would be transformed into something like the following:

```
| OfficeLocation |  PersonID_1 | PersonID_2 | PersonID_3 | PersonID_4| PersonID_5| PersonID_6|
| -------------- | ----------- |----------- |----------- |-----------|-----------|-----------|
| 321            |      2323   |    2355    |   1234     |  7899     |  32091    |  777      |
| 1654           |      4232   |            |            |           |           |           |
| 121243         |       345   |    343     |    111     |           |           |           |
```

I was thinking of perhaps doing something like just joining the "OfficePers" table on itself multiple times but I'm not sure what function I could use to parse out each Person ID - I'm familiar with using Max and Min but that wouldn't work with a case of having more than 2 Person IDs at the same location.

Comment: Do you know beforehand the maximum number of persons in each office? If not, are you OK showing at most six per office (even for offices who may have 20 persons)? How do you choose which six you show, out of 20 persons in the same office? And even for offices with six or fewer persons, how do you decide who goes in the first column, who goes in the second, etc.? (If "it doesn't matter, any order is fine", that is a valid answer, but don't let us **guess** that that's the answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method is to combine these into a single column using `listagg()`:

```
select OfficeLocation,
       listagg(personid, ',') within group (order by personid) as personids
from t
group by OfficeLocation;
```

I do not recommend putting the values in separate columns for several reasons.  First, you don't know how many columns you will need.  Second, you can do this using dynamic SQL, but you cannot create a view for the result.  Third, the same person could -- in theory -- appear in multiple rows, but the person would likely be in different columns.

EDIT:

If you want exactly six columns, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select OfficeLocation,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then PersonId) as PersonId_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then PersonId) as PersonId_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then PersonId) as PersonId_3,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then PersonId) as PersonId_4,
       max(case when seqnum = 5 then PersonId) as PersonId_5,
       max(case when seqnum = 6 then PersonId) as PersonId_6
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by OfficeLocation order by personid) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by OfficeLocation;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon - the thing is, the results of the query are feeding a form. So there are say 6 separate sections on the form where I would be putting Person_1 's info, and then a separate section to put Person_2's info etc. At max I would need 6 columns - I should have mentioned that earlier.

Comment: combine it with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199849/split-varchar-into-separate-columns-in-oracle and you're there. You may need some case for the shorter rows

Comment: @Jonathan . . . If you know you want exactly six columns, then conditional aggregation is appropriate.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - this works like a gem - thanks so much!