# How do I split entire full name column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle, I've got a full name column. I want to split that into a first name column and a last name column. SQL code?

Comment: Sample data is required. This isn't so simple as you could have middle names, suffixes, etc.

Comment: What if there are more than one names(or surnames)?

Comment: For the future, good to know this is tricky. In this particular case, there are only 40 rows, and only first and last names.

Comment: Does this answer your question... [Split varchar into separate columns in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199849/split-varchar-into-separate-columns-in-oracle)

Comment: It seems that is good for one row maybe, but not for a full column.

Comment: No, that's not right. First, take the example and replace "column_one" with "full_name". Then remove `t.` if you don't plan to alias your table name.

Comment: This didn't run either: SELECT SUBSTR(FULL_NAME, 1, INSTR(FIRST_NAME, ' ')-1),
SUBSTR(FULL_NAME, INSTR(LAST_NAME, ' ')+1);

Comment: What are the 1's and ' ' for? In this database the full name column just has first name space last name, like "Joe Blow"

Comment: That's still not right. Should be `..INSTR(FULL_NAME)`. See the answer below. The `' '` is your space delimiter, while the `-1` and `+1` is defining where to take the text in relation to the delimiter.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation of '  ' and -1 +1.

Comment: What are SUBSTR and INSTR short for? In code SET first_name = SUBSTR(full_name, 1, INSTR(full_name, ' ')-1),
last_name = SUBSTR(full_name, INSTR(full_name, ' ')+1), I get that ' ' is the space/delimiter between the first and last names. And I get that -1 allows SQL to find where the first name ends, and +1 allows SQL to find where the last name begins. But what about the 1 after full_name,? What does that indicate? That the space between between the delimiters is one space?

Answer (score 1):

If it's not working for all rows, then your rows have different delimiters.

```
with my_data as (
  select 'john smith' as full_name from dual union all
  select 'rudy chan' from dual union all
  select 'h gonzalez' from dual
  )
SELECT full_name, 
  SUBSTR(full_name, 1, INSTR(full_name, ' ')-1) AS first_name,
  SUBSTR(full_name, INSTR(full_name, ' ')+1) AS last_name
  FROM my_data
```

| FULL_NAME | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| john smith | john | smith |
| rudy chan | rudy | chan |
| h gonzalez | h | gonzalez |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vUVSktXQ)

**UPDATE**

Based on your comments below, you are looking for how to ADD columns to a table. Broke this out into two steps....

```
--adding two columns
Alter table my_data 
  add (
    first_name varchar(20), 
    last_name varchar(20)
  );
```

```
--update the newly added columns
update my_data 
  set first_name = SUBSTR(full_name, 1, INSTR(full_name, ' ')-1),
      last_name = SUBSTR(full_name, INSTR(full_name, ' ')+1);
```

```
select *
from my_data
```

| FULL_NAME | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| john smith | john | smith |
| rudy chan | rudy | chan |
| h gonzalez | h | gonzalez |

Comment: SELECT full_name, 
  SUBSTR(full_name, 1, INSTR(full_name, ' ')-1) AS first_name,
  SUBSTR(full_name, INSTR(full_name, ' ')+1) AS last_name
  FROM my_data  -- Worked Great! But, and now I'm realizing, that's only a query/view. How do I actually modify the table like this?

Answer (score 0):

Isolated's option is just fine (according to the task); another option might be **regular expressions**.

It looks *simpler* and works OK on small data sets, such as your table with 40 rows; for large tables, e.g. hundreds of millions rows, `substr + instr` combination will most probably work way faster.

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * from my_data;

FULL_NAME  FIRST_NAME           LAST_NAME
---------- -------------------- --------------------
john smith
rudy chan
h gonzalez
```

Query:

```
SQL> update my_data set
  2    first_name = regexp_substr(full_name, '^\w+'),
  3    last_name  = regexp_substr(full_name, '\w+$');

3 rows updated.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from my_data;

FULL_NAME  FIRST_NAME           LAST_NAME
---------- -------------------- --------------------
john smith john                 smith
rudy chan  rudy                 chan
h gonzalez h                    gonzalez

SQL>
```